# show toast notification without clicking on a link or button

Tags: html, css, toast

I don't know how to explain this clearly, the following code notification shows on clicking the link/an href element.
I would like to load it on page load itself, without click, how ?

```
<a href="" data-toast="snackbar-7">
<i class="fa font-14 fa-check color-green-dark"></i>
<span>Confirmation Snackbar</span>
<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
</a>


<div id="snackbar-7" class="snackbar-toast color-white bg-green-dark mb-4" data-bs-delay="3000" data-bs-autohide="true">
<h1 class="color-white font-20 pt-3 pb-3 mb-n4">Success</h1>
<p class="color-white mb-0 pb-1">Changes applied succesfully.</p>
</div>
```

The intention is to show notification on database data submission using PHP.

Comment: It looks like you're using some library or custom code that makes an element with `data-toast` open a notification element. You should ask the person who wrote this code how to do it, as you don't seem to be familiar with this custom code.

Comment: Is there also some JavaScript? Maybe some action is happening with onClick event? Maybe it should be replaced with onLoad or something similar. Try to take a look at https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/toasts/ and https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_snackbar.asp

Comment: One way is to keep a value in php session, for an example $_SESSION['toast1'] = "1"; 
Now you can check if the session value is 1 or not when page loads and display the toast inside the if else statement.